# Why is my functionn printing none in python

Tags: python

I wrote this code

```
def function1():
    message = "I am function 1"

def functin2():
    message = "I am function 2"

print(function1())
print(functin2())
```

but i get this result
[image]

plz help

Comment: Because you have to `return` from functions. They return `None` implicitly otherwise

Comment: Please put error messages as code, not a screenshot and not as a link to a screenshot

Comment: Python functions as a default returns None. I suggest that you study a 101 course, before trying out.

Answer (score 1):

your function doesnt return anything. You need to add a return statement.

```py
def function1():
    message = "I am function 1"
    return message

def functin2():
    message = "I am function 2"
    return message
```

Comment: Consider emphasizing that "anything" equals `None` in this context